# Как обезопасить себя от WSO - веб-шелл?

Tags: vds, shell, сервер, php

- 1.Я разобрался что на сервер залили WSO - веб-шелл, но вот с трудом могу понять каким образом.
- 2.У меня все сайты лежат на серваке на одном логине, т.е. если получить доступ к директории какого то сайта, то из неё можно выйти на уровень выше, и получить доступ к другому сайту, верно?

  К чему я это, у меня есть один сайт на joomla 1.7 - я script нашел в нем, а лишний код обнаружил в нескольких index.php и на других сайтах.
- 3.Может быть мне стоит или ТАК И НУЖНО ДЕЛАТЬ -> для каждого сайта свой аккаунт и свой доступ по ftp?

Всем буду благодарен за любую информацию по этому поводу!

Может быть кто скинет ссылку на то как этот Shell можно залить на сервак, я ведь если пойму как его залить, соответственно смогу себя обезопасить, верно?

Comment: Эх...ладно отвечу сам на свой вопрос, вот ссылка,  http://www.revisium.com/kb/ , информация очень хорошо изложена и очень полезна.

Answer (score 3):

Как правило такие скрипты заливаются через бреши в безопасности общеизвестных CMS, а joomla это вообще одна из самых распространенных. Для профилактики держите CMS в актуальном состоянии, следите за выходом заплаток и релизов безопасности. Если позволяет лицензия, маскируйте используемую вами CMS, убирая копирайты и меняя названия релизов и специфичных идентификаторов. Кстати, на то, что ваш сайт был атакован через дыру CMS говорит сразу два фактора - первый скрипт залит в папку CMS, что обычно происходит, когда скрипты-роботы работают в автоматическом режиме, второе - у вас устаревшая версия CMS, вы указывайте 1.7, а на русскоязычном сайте http://joomlaportal.ru/ уже пишут про заплатки для 3.1.4

Comment: Григорий, спасибо большое за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Установить и настроить на аппачи моды, mod_security2 и suhosin.http://htf.net.ua/zachita_php5_pri_pomochi_suhosin

И плюс вот это сделать - http://htf.net.ua/php_security_web_shell